# How to alter the prefixes EPiServer is adding to src attributes in html

Tags: episerver

I have a fragment of html which is contained in a property of a templated EPiServer page, within that html there is an `img` tag which has a relative url in it.

When the page is viewed, I can see the src attribute of the tag has been altered to have the prefix `/ProjectName/Templates/Pages/`.

I understand that this is being done by `HtmlRewriteToExternal` so that image files that are stored alongside the aspx template (which does indeed live in `Templates\Pages`) are located correctly, however the image which is intended to be part of the html fragment is in my case actually stored under `PageFiles/nnn/` (where nnn is actually the parent page's `PageFolderID`), and I need to somehow make the altered html reflect that.

I've created a class that inherits from `FriendlyUrlRewriteProvider` and registered my class. I can debug the application, and watch the requests go through the overridden methods, but I still can't see where the prefix is being added or get any idea how to change it. I can alter the src tag to a different relative path in my class, but the prefix is still being added.

I've read everything I can find on the EPiServer url rewriting, but can't find anything that hints as to where this prefix is being added or how to stop that or change it.

Things I've read:

- http://blogs.interakting.co.uk/post/File-Extensions-and-URL-Rewriting-in-EPiServer.aspx
- http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/blog/2008/05/07/disable-episerver-urlrewriter-interference/ (this may contain the answer I'm looking for)
- http://labs.kaliko.com/2010/11/prevent-episerver-urlrewrite.html
- http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/episerver-friendly-urls-for-paginated-pages-and-why-the-asplinkbutton-must-die/510
- http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2008/7/create-a-custom-url-rewrite-provider-for-episerver/
- http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/4/publishing-plain-html-pages-in-episerver/
- http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/Developers%20Guide/Friendly%20URL.htm
- http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6.1/html/T_EPiServer_Web_UrlRewriteModule.htm
- http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Ruwen/Dates/111218/112064/112154/
- http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Magnus-Strale/Dates/2011/3/Do-we-really-need-yet-another-HTML-parser/
- http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Yugeen-Klimenko/Dates/2011/6/How-EPiServer-URL-Rewriting-works/
- http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=46869

---

I'm open to completely different solutions for what I'm actually trying to achieve, which is as follows:

I have multiple independent sets of static html files and related image / css / js files, which I'm trying to store / publish with EPiServer. The structure of each set looks something like

- setfolder/

  - htmlfileA.html
  - htmlfileB.html
  - css/

    - styles.css
  - images/

    - piccy1.png
    - piccy2.png
  - js/

    - magic.js

I've figured that I should create an EPiServer page for the set, and then child pages for each html file, storing the html from the files in a property of the child pages. Currently I'm storing the related static files in the PageFiles of the relevant setfolder page, as that seems to be the most logically consistent place to put them.

Comment: Someone with a similar issue and no resolution http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=41534

Comment: Another unanswered question: "Prevent UrlReWrite for a specific page type" http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=19395

Comment: I've posted a similar question to the EPiServer forums. http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=57845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give the best solution without seeing it all infront of you. But one easy way is to alter the HTML-code when you print the property to the page.

Like <%= ChangeRelativeLinks(CurrentPage["HtmlCode"] as string) %>

And in the ChangeRelativeLinks(string htmlCode) you do a regexp or similar that changes relative links and images to the pagedir as an absolute path.

Comment: Having changed the relative links to absolute links the html rewriting that happens when the page is about to be sent to the client now ignores them. Yay! Here's my absolute path prefix being generated: `ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/PageFiles/{0}/", GetPage(CurrentPage.ParentLink)["PageFolderID"]));`

Comment: More of the code-behind I've used is available here: https://gist.github.com/2291964 (feel free to copy paste the code into your answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the images in PageFiles which is a Virtual Path Provider you should be able to get the url to your file simply by using the API. On the PageData class (ie CurrentPage in your template) you have a method called GetPageDirectory() which gets the page folder.

You can read more about VPP concepts here:

http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6.1/Developers%20Guide/Core%20Features/File%20System/File%20System%20and%20VPPs.htm

No need for a url rewrite provider for this I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made use of GetPageDirectory() so I know what you mean, I even created an extension for that https://gist.github.com/2205546/5258de36e14b6487d38978a6e1e05f93ce4a8c89#L37 The problem I have is that the whole html chunk will be in an html page-property set by a user, thus I don't have the opportunity to set the src attribute directly. So although I can find out the path of the image programmatically, I can't figure out how to apply that path to the src attribute, or redirect the browser's request. Fiddling with the html rewriter is my current best guess.